# Convert Expression<Func<T1>> to Expression<Func<T1, T2>>

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, lambda

I have the following C# code, that gets the member name from lambda expression:

```
public static class ObjectInformation<T>
{
    public static string GetPropertyName<TProp>(Expression<Func<T, TProp>> propertyLambda)
    {
        var memberExpression = propertyLambda.Body as MemberExpression;
        if (memberExpression == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentException("Lambda must return a property.");
        }

        return memberExpression.Member.Name;
    }
}

public static class ObjectInformation
{
   public static string GetPropertyName<T>(Expression<Func<T>> propertyLambda)
    {
        var memberExpression = propertyLambda.Body as MemberExpression;
        if (memberExpression == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentException("Lambda must return a property.");    
        }

        return memberExpression.Member.Name;
    }
}
```

I call the methods like this:

```
ObjectInformation<RemoteCollectionContentViewModel>.GetPropertyName(e => e.SomeProperty);
ObjectInformation.GetPropertyName(() => SomeProperty)
```

I would like the second method to use the first one (not to duplicate the code), so I need to convert `Func<T>` to `Func<T, TProp>`. How could I achieve that?

Comment: make `<Func<T>` and `<Func<T, TProp>` another generic parameter

Comment: @SamLeach Won't syntactic sugar be broken by that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's no easy way to convert expression type. You'll have to rebuild the whole expression tree. It isn't worth the trouble. There's a good old way of extracting the common logic:

```
public static class ObjectInformation
{
    public static string GetPropertyName<T, TProp> (Expression<Func<T, TProp>> propertyLambda)
    {
        return GetPropertyName((LambdaExpression)propertyLambda);
    }

    public static string GetPropertyName<T> (Expression<Func<T>> propertyLambda)
    {
        return GetPropertyName((LambdaExpression)propertyLambda);
    }

    private static string GetPropertyName (LambdaExpression propertyLambda)
    {
        var memberExpression = propertyLambda.Body as MemberExpression;
        if (memberExpression == null)
            throw new ArgumentException("Lambda must return a property.");
        return memberExpression.Member.Name;
    }
}
```

Comment: Seems really nice answer, but how can I call the method like I used to before with ObjectInformation<RemoteCollectionContentViewModel>.GetPropertyName(e => e.SomeProperty);?

Comment: @Darxis Your options: 1. Make the third overload internal and move the first overload into a separate class. 2. Call method like this: `ObjectInformation.GetPropertyName((RemoteCollectionContentViewModel e) => e.SomeProperty)`. C# can resolve all type parameters when the method is called like this.